# MySQLi - Should every statement be prepared?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I know its supposed to improve performance and clean strings, but lets say there are no variables?

Might just be a

```
SELECT COUNT( `column` ) AS count FROM `table`
```

1. Should that be prepared?
2. Is there any case that a `SELECT` statement should not be prepared?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a general rule, you should prepare statements that take variables from somewhere else.  Usually this includes `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements, `SELECT`s and `DELETE`s with `WHERE` clauses, and stored procedure calls with arguments.

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question at all.

Answer (score 4):

A general rule: If the query contains user input, it should be prepared. Otherwise, you don't have to. Your example doesn't need to be prepared.